# Permissions Level issue...I can still delete

Tags: permissions, item-level-permissions, custom-permission-level, sharepoint-permissions, item-deleted

I have a group where a person can add, edit, and view but not delete
I put myself in this group but I can still delete.
I thought it was because I have higher level access at the site level.
So I tested it with another user and verified they do not any admin level permissions.  I put them in the non delete group but they too can also delete.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you used the Check Permissions button in permissions to make sure that you and the other test user don't have farm/site collection admin rights, or increased levels of access through another group?

Comment: Share the screenshot of permissions for that particular user on the entity(list/library) where he is able to delete...

Comment: @brendan-w, I was confusing permissions to a view rather than a list.  I thought I had the permissions set to a view...but I found out that is not how it works (sorry new to SharePoint).  So the individual is in another group that has contribute access to the list so no matter what view I use, he'll have contribute rights regardless of view. Since this site has unique permissions, this shouldn't be a problem in my case.  The only issue I have now is that the individual cannot edit.  I'll post that in an separate post.  I'll count your post as the answer (he was in another post).

Comment: @adams-j No worries, we were all new at one point! Your conclusion is accurate, and list views do not have their own permissions. Permissions on the list itself are going to be the same across all views. Glad I was able to help!